# Take image from Gallery to ImageView in Android

Tags: android

I try to display a Image from Gallery to `ImageView`

This is my Code so far:

```
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        pictureActionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        pictureActionIntent.setType("image/*");
                        pictureActionIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                        startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent, GALLERY_PICTURE);
                    }
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();

                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        cursor.close();

                        taskImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.taskPhotoImage);

                        taskImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                        }
```

But there is nothing displayed. Just blank a `ImageView`.

Where is my mistake? I've read so many tutorials. But all of them shows the same solution.

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the below code. it works for me.

mainactivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >
    </ImageView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLoadPicture"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:onClick="loadImagefromGallery"
        android:text="Load Picture" >
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
    String image_str,res,imgDecodableString,the_string_response;
    Bitmap img;
    Exception e;
    int contentLength;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
        //Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        // Start the Intent
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                // Get the Image from data

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                // Get the cursor
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
                img = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory
                        .decodeFile(imgDecodableString), 500, 500, false);
                imgView.setImageBitmap(img);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to change it using rotation, but I've done this code far earlier and don't have the updated one

Comment: I see it's just on one picture. The other one aren't upside down.

Answer (score 2):

Here is code i have used. use it according to your need

```
private static final int GALLERY_PHOTO = 111;
private void pickImage(){
     Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
     chooserIntent.setType("image/*");
     startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, GALLERY_PHOTO);
}
```

in your `onActivityResult()` you should use like this.

```
 if (resultCode == GALLERY_PHOTO && data.getData() != null) {
        String filePath = GetFilePathFromDevice.getPath(YourActivityName.this, data.getData());
        taskImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.taskPhotoImage);
        taskImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath));
  }
```

Here is class used for getting file path from `URI`.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public final class GetFilePathFromDevice {

    /**
     * Get file path from URI
     *
     * @param context context of Activity
     * @param uri     uri of file
     * @return path of given URI
     */
    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{split[1]};
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {column};
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
}
```